# Having issues with Craft install on Laravel Valet.

Tags: install, installation

I'm having some trouble getting Craft to install with Laravel Valet. All I'm getting on the .dev, .dev/admin, .dev/index.php/admin? is the 'service unavailable'. Not sure if it's just new to Craft or something very unique to me. Thanks in advance for any help.

**db.php**

```
<?php
return array(

    'server' => '127.0.0.1',

    'database' => 'activeendurance',

    'user' => 'root',

    'password' => '',

    'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
);
```

**craft.log**

```
    2017/05/12 20:32:46 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "cache" application component
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (595)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (137)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/bootstrap.php (190)
2017/05/12 20:32:46 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "path" application component
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (595)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/cache/FileCache.php (41)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/services/CacheService.php (114)
2017/05/12 20:32:46 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "request" application component
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (595)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (138)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/bootstrap.php (190)
2017/05/12 20:32:46 [trace] [system.caching.Craft\FileCache] Serving "usePathInfo" from cache
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/services/CacheService.php (180)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/services/ConfigService.php (392)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/services/HttpRequestService.php (1158)
2017/05/12 20:32:46 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "urlManager" application component
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (595)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/services/HttpRequestService.php (1498)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/services/HttpRequestService.php (1165)
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "log" application component
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (595)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (139)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/bootstrap.php (190)
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "coreMessages" application component
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (595)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (142)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/bootstrap.php (190)
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [trace] [system.db.CDbConnection] Opening DB connection
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (871)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (591)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (80)
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [trace] [system.db.CDbCommand] Querying SQL: SHOW TABLES LIKE 'craft_%'
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/db/schemas/MysqlSchema.php (312)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/db/DbConnection.php (90)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (98)
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [profile] [system.db.CDbCommand.query] begin:system.db.CDbCommand.query(SHOW TABLES LIKE 'craft_%')
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [profile] [system.db.CDbCommand.query] end:system.db.CDbCommand.query(SHOW TABLES LIKE 'craft_%')
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] Craft\HttpException in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:800
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(203): Craft\WebApp->_processInstallRequest()
#1 /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#2 /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#3 /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/public/index.php(19): require_once('/Users/jfrank/a...')
#4 /Users/jfrank/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php(133): require('/Users/jfrank/a...')
#5 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/
---
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "errorHandler" application component
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (595)
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "templates" application component
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (595)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php (170)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php (281)
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "i18n" application component
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (595)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (639)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior.php (959)
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "plugins" application component
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (595)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php (1444)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php (192)
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [trace] [system.caching.Craft\FileCache] Serving "omitScriptNameInUrls" from cache
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/services/CacheService.php (180)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/services/ConfigService.php (303)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/helpers/UrlHelper.php (411)
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "messages" application component
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (595)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/Craft.php (385)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/cf/cf8c6e6b352d46fe66a7bf9ae1be09d65a54a3f0149bcb6418616181581f6d54.php (26)
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [trace] [system.CModule] Loading "resources" application component
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (595)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/helpers/UrlHelper.php (273)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php (518)
2017/05/12 20:32:47 [trace] [system.caching.Craft\FileCache] Serving "resourcePath:css/craft.css" from cache
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/services/CacheService.php (180)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/services/ResourcesService.php (36)
in /Users/jfrank/activeSites/activeendurance/craft/app/helpers/UrlHelper.php (277)
```

Comment: What happens if you visit `activeendurance.dev/index.php?p=admin/install` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Talked with Justin via DM on the Craft Slack. As per that discussion, here was the solution:*

The Valet docs are extremely misleading. When detailing how to use the `park` command, they list running `laravel new blog` as one of the steps. This command has to do with creating a Laravel site and is not necessary at all (and in fact, as seen in this instance, sometimes destructive) for running Craft sites or even for sites using other CMSs like Wordpress etc.

To fix it, remove the `activeendurance` folder, recreate it, and put the Craft folders/files back in there.